# Remove a dictionay with specific id from list of dictionaries

Tags: python

```
data_list = [
    {"id": 1,},
    {"id": 2,},
    {"id": 3,},
    {"id": 4,},
    {"id": 5,},
    {"id": 6,},
]
```

As above shown ,i have a list of dictionaries. I want to delete the dictionary with id 4 , without using linear searching.

Comment: Cool.  What have you tried?  Please post your code.

Comment: Are the elements guaranteed to be in order? Otherwise there's no way to find the element with a particular id unless you iterate through the items and look at the id of each one. Are you ruling that out?

Comment: Couldn't you create a dictionary with the id as key? And then use .pop(key)?

Comment: @khelwood . yah, elements are guaranteed to be in order.

Comment: Then you can use a [binary search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_algorithm).

Comment: @andreas , that logic will work. but not for me, here. if i were to change data to that form, it means, about 1-2 hr extra work.

Comment: @khelwood thats the only option it seems, i will try then.!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you said they are in order I would do binary search

```
def bsearch(data_list,x):
    lo,hi=0,len(data_list)-1
    while lo<=hi:
        mid=(lo+hi)//2
        if data_list[mid]["id"]==x:
            return mid

        if data_list[mid]["id"]>x:
            hi=mid-1

        elif data_list[mid]["id"]<x:
            lo=mid+1
    return -1


data_list = [
    {"id": 1,},
    {"id": 2,},
    {"id": 3,},
    {"id": 4,},
    {"id": 5,},
    {"id": 6,},
]

idx=bsearch(data_list,4)
if idx:
    data_list.pop(idx)
else:
    print("value not found")

print(data_list)
```